# how to build vim with cscope feature enabled

Tags: vim

Since I the vim I used does not contain cscope feature , I need to rebuild vim from source code to be able to use cscope  . After a little bit google, I didn't not find a "exactly how to answer" ,so turn to stack** for help .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wget ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.2.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf vim-7.2.tar.bz2
cd vim72
./configure --enable-cscope
make
make install
```

If the `./configure` line fails, be prepared to install the headers for required libraries.  If you're using your distribution's package manager, they will usually be in the `-dev` versions of the library packages.

For more information, check the configuration options available:

```
./configure --help
```